# Comment section wont post comments

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I have a problem in my code. When I post a comment aka when I hit the button, it wont show in the comment field before I refresh the site. Can somebody help me with that? It would be truly appreciated!

```
<?php
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die(mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM kommentar";

$resultat = mysqli_query($db,$query);
if (!$resultat) echo "<b>FEIL: ikke i stand til å sende.</b>";

$rows = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$rows[] = $row;
}


$query2 = sprintf("select * from kommentar");

// Sender spørring til databasen og tester på om den gjekk OK 
$resultat2=mysqli_query($db, $query2);    
if (!$resultat2) echo "<b>FEIL: ikkje i stand til å senda.</b>";

// Initialisere rows2 som ein 'array'  
$rows2 = array();  
// Henter verdiar til rows1 frå database-svaret  
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {  
    $rows2[] = $row2;    
}

if (isset($_GET['id']) && intval($_GET['id']) > 0) {

// Hentar id frå querystreng
$id = $_GET['id'];

// "Cast" id til integer, dvs. gjer om id til heiltal
$id = (int) $id;
}  
?>


 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Kommentarfelt</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h3> Kommentarer: </h3> 
     <?php foreach($rows2 as $row2): ?>  
             <?php echo $row2['tekst']; ?> 
             Lagt inn <?php echo $row2['opprettet']; ?> av <?php echo
  $row2['navn']; ?><br>                                                   
     <?php endforeach; ?>
     <h4> Skriv ny kommentar: </h4>
     <form method="POST" action="test_envy.php?id=<?php echo $row1['id']; ?>">   
     <b>Navn:</b><br>   
<input type="navn" name="navn"><br>   
<b>Kommentar:</b><br>
<textarea cols="60" rows="6" name="tekst"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="sendknapp" value="Send"></form> 
</body>
<?php  

/*if ($_POST["sendknapp"] == "Send")*/


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")

{    
//mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); /* server, username, passord */
//mysql_select_db("mydb");   
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");     
$navn=$_POST["navn"];  
$tekst=$_POST["tekst"];    
$query ="INSERT INTO kommentar (navn, tekst)";    
$query.="VALUES ('$navn','$tekst')";    
$resultat=mysqli_query($db, $query);    
if ($resultat) {
printf("Kommentar registrert", mysqli_insert_id($db));
echo ("<a href='vg.no" . $id . "';> Oppdater side </a>");}

else printf("ikkje i stand til å senda query:%s", $query);;  
}    
?>
```

Comment: You should have this whole thing handled by and AJAX call.  So someone posts the comment, AJAX sends to sever, and updates the page with no need for a refresh.

Comment: You should be using the mysqli_real_escape_string for your inputs as this can prevent data being added to your tables http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

Until page reload, you need to temporarily add the comment via AJAX.

Something like this:

```
// Add this line in your form
<input type='hidden' id='ajaxURL' value='test_envy.php?id=<?php echo $row1['id'] ?>'>

// Add this to your HTML
<script>
$('input[name="sendknapp"]').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); // Stops your page from reloading

    var ajaxurl = $('#ajaxURL').val();

    $.ajax({ url: ajaxurl, // The URL you're gonna pass to the script
         data: {action: 'test'}, // Variables you wanna pass to the function
         type: 'post',
         success: function(response) {
             // Get your variables from the response
             alert(response); // This will show you the response in an alert box
             // $('#elementID').append("<a href='" + variable + "'> Oppdater side </a>");
         }
    });
});
</script>
```

So this **should** popup a box with a response in it. You need to tweak from here on. Your PHP needs to echo the response and then you append it to your HTML.

You need to pass variables via **data**. It all depends on what your php script does... In this case test_envy.php.

One more essential thing I forgot to mention is you need to add this line to the head of your html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
```

This is to load jQuery on your page... Without it, the script won't work.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Can I just add all of this into my PHP document and it will work, or do I have to download something?

Comment: Oh no you need to add more stuff... let me try to fix it up a bit so that it could work for you...